# Python/Django - Indirect bidirectional m2m relationship?

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
class Reference(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('title'))

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s" % (self.title)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name = _('bibliographic reference')
      verbose_name_plural = _('bibliographic references')


class Relation(models.Model):
  reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)
  circuit = models.ManyToManyField('Circuit', related_name = 'relation_circuit', verbose_name = _('Circuits'))

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s " %(self.reference)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name = _('relation')
      verbose_name_plural = _('relations')


class Circuit(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('name'))
  reference = models.ManyToManyField(Relation, through=Relation.circuit.through, related_name='relation_circuit', verbose_name = _('Bibliographic References'))

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s" % (self.name)

  class Meta:
      verbose_name = _('circuit')
      verbose_name_plural = _('circuits')
```

Relation is shown as an inline in Reference. 
I need to create a bidirectional relationship between my Circuits and the References, but I have no idea how to show all my References instead only those who had a Relation, cause Relation is between them.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a through table? As in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ ?

Comment: This code is weird to say the least. Could you describe in your own words what are you actually trying to achieve? If you'd draw ERD that would be even more helpful.

Comment: I think not. The solution I have published works with a through table, but when I'm in Circuits, I can only see those references who have a relation, not all the references in my Reference model. Maybe I can define the through table in other way, but I don't know how. Any idea? :)

Comment: In one hand, I have References with different Relations between Circuits and other variables. In the other hand, I have Circuits with several information, including its Reference. One Circuit could be related to different References, and a Reference could be related to different Circuits too.
When I want to add another Reference to my Circuit, I only can choose between those Reference who had a Relation. But a Reference could have no Relations. How can I create a bidirectional relationship between Reference and Circuit when Relation is between them?

Comment: I think you are confusing things... you just want a ManyToMany to Reference on the Circuit model, with Relation as the through table (though you only need an explicit through table if you're adding more fields to the through model, which are not shown in your code at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my starting point.

```
 class Reference(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   relations = models.ManyToManyField('Relation', related_name="reference_relations", null=True, blank=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s" % (self.title,)


class Relation(models.Model):
  reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)
  circuit = models.ForeignKey('Circuit')

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s <-> %s " %(self.reference, self.circuit)



class Circuit(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  relations = models.ManyToManyField(Relation, related_name="circuit_relations", null=True, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s" % (self.name)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from web.models import *


class RelationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relation

class CircuitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        RelationInline,
    ]

class ReferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        RelationInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Reference,ReferenceAdmin)
admin.site.register(Relation)
admin.site.register(Circuit, CircuitAdmin)
```

Of course you can do this without the through table, but my preference is to keep relations simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood what you need, but wouldn't a table with a foreignKey to both be enough?

Something like

```
 class Reference(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('title'))


 class Circuit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('name'))


 class Relation(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit)
```

Then you can link them by creating an instance of Relation like so:

```
 circuit = Circuit(name="cool_circuit")
 reference = Reference(title="cool_reference")

 relation = Relation(reference=reference, circuit=circuit)
```

It's also easy to get all references linked to some circuit

```
 circuit = Circuit.objects.get(id=1)

 references_linked_to_circuit_1 = Reference.objects.filter(relation__circuit=circuit)
```

and likewise for all circuits linked to a reference

```
 reference = Circuit.objects.get(id=1)

 circuits_linked_to_reference_1 = Reference.objects.filter(relation__reference=reference)
```